# Natural ways to mean someone is stalling another

Tags: word-choice, idioms, collocations, colloquial-language, conversation

Example: If a woman is asked to get married and tries to get time to answer because she feels insecure but doesn't want to say it. I could tell she's stalling the man. But if I wanted to sound more natural, what should I say?

What would it be the most popular ways (not slang) to put it?

Comment: "Keeping him waiting for an answer"?

Comment: A common idiomatic usage in this context is *She's [**playing for time***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/play%20for%20time) (trying to make something happen later instead of sooner). It's "popular, colloquial", but I wouldn't say the usage is "slang". It's not very "formal" though - that would be ***temporize***.

Answer (score 2):

"Stalling" is the ideal word:

> speak or act in a deliberately vague way in order to gain more time to deal with something; prevaricate. (oxford)

It is usually intransitive. "She is stalling <s>the man</s> for time.

Answer (score 2):

Another common phrase is "putting him off". Ex: He asked her several times for her decision, but she kept **putting him off**.